# Find text of HTML element using selenium WebDriver in Java which has inherited element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get text of an element which contains another element in it and a text. But it return something from the inherited element and the text. Is there a way I can get only the text?

[image]

Comment: Which **text** are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2):

The text is in the `<h5>` tag, you need to locate that element

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class='img-circle owner-image']/..")).getText();
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way of locating element

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@class,'img-circle')]")).getText();
```